# Hadoop Warning Message : 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'

Tags: hadoop

I am new to hadoop and have installed hadoop 2.2.0 on the centos box. for any of the hdfs command i run below mentioned is the warning message i am getting. Any help is appreciated.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /data/hadoop-2.2.0/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
14/02/25 11:52:45 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable.
```

JAVA_HOME is set to oracle hotspot jdk1.7

Answer (score 0):

Able to get some answer, centos running on 64 bit version and hadoop default installation is 32 bit. So either need to compile on the centos or ignore the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native 
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
```

Add these two lines in .bashrc and reopen your terminal and try restarting hadoop.

Comment: hello, I have already included this. even though it gives same problem.

Answer (score 0):

`execstack -c <libfile>`, or link it with `-z noexecstack`. If you Got this error means simply open `./bashrc`  via `sudo gedit .bashrc` and add these two lines:

```
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native 
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
```

Next step to update .bashrc file:

```
source .bashrc
```

Finally:

```
./start-all.sh
```

Finished. Now it's working fine.